Dovecot authentication via group for sharing user mailbox
This is on a dovecot + postfix setup.
Postfix authenticates via a unix socket onto dovecot.
There is no virtual user.
Dovecot authenticates the system users via PAM.
We would like to give access to a a few mailboxes to several users.
It does not seem to correspond to what dovecot documentation shows as shared mailboxes: we do not want/need folders to appear nested in someone else's folders.
Rather we want to allow someone to add a mailbox in his client authenticating with his own username/password.
Hence the idea of giving access to some mailboxes via a system group.
All users belonging to a system group should be able to access the mailbox with the same username as that group.
That way we can simply create a dummy user with his own group for each mailbox to share.
Then simply add all necessary users to the group of the mailbox user.
Would that work out simply ?
Like:

user_s is created belonging to group_s
user_a is added to group_s
--> user_a can access mailbox of user_s with his own credentials.

Would be simpler than reverse dicts etc, and simpler to manage as file access and mailbox access goes with the same groups. And also avoid having nested folders.
Any simple way to return a successful authentication on user_s if user_a belongs to group_s ?
Like via  some override argument perhaps ?
Thanks in advance !
Currently:
All is stored in /var/mail, as per documentation an some Howtos.
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
userdb {
  driver = passwd
  override_fields = uid=mail gid=mail home=/var/mail/%d/%n
}

